# Creating bitmap on background thread stalls render thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, graphics

A bit of background: I am animating a display of a sonar recording playback. The sonar recording files are large (typically 100 - 600MB), so segments are loaded as required. The guts of it is that we pre-index the sonar files, then use a memory mapped file to load chunks of data as required. The data is then used to create a bitmap - very simply, as the data consists of bytes and we just map those to colours using an 8 bit palette.

For performance reasons, we do all the loading in the background and render each segment in its own drawing visual. This works fine, and manually scrolling the view (or jumping to a specific location) gives very nice performance.

The issue that we are having - and its a niggle really, but a very irritating one - is that we get glitchy playback at higher speeds. I have narrowed down the cause of this to the moment at which we create a writeable bitmap in a thread pool thread. The code is as follows:

```
BitmapPalette bmp = new BitmapPalette(Palette);

WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(segment_bytes.ping_width, segment_bytes.height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed8, bmp);

Int32Rect update_rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, segment_bytes.ping_width, segment_bytes.height);
wb.WritePixels(update_rect, segment_bytes.data, segment_bytes.ping_width, 0);

wb.Freeze();

_element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
new Action(delegate()
{
    brush.set_image_brush(wb);
}));
```

The set_image_brush call just sets the image source of a brush that is used to render the segment (via drawRectangle) and start a short opacity animation.

Through trial and error (commenting out bits of code) I have determined that it is the constructor of the WriteableBitmap that is causing the slow down/glitches, for every segment and much more noticeable on larger segments. So even though this is all taking place in a thread pool thread, the creation of the WB is taking place on the render thread (UI thread?).

Is there any way at all to get around this issue?

thanks,
Matt

Edit: Just to be absolutely clear, it is the creation of the WB that causes this. If I remove the code to set the image on the UI thread, and render my segments as outlined rectangles instead I can still see the glitches. Likewise if I remove the writepixels call. Simply creating the WB is causing the issue, and I have no idea how I would stop this..

Comment: How about creating a BitmapSource directly (by [BitmapSource.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.Create(v=vs.110).aspx)) instead of creating a WriteableBitmap and then calling WritePixels?

Comment: Worth a try Clemens, but unfortunately the behaviour is exactly the same.

Comment: Would it make sense to reuse existing WriteableBitmaps, or do they have a different size each time?

Comment: Unfortunately they can be a wide range of sizes, and are created and destroyed as required..

Answer (score 0):

Try using Dispatcher.CheckAccess() method as shown below:

```
        if (_element.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            new Action(delegate()
            {
                brush.set_image_brush(wb);

            }));
        }
        else
        {
            _element.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
            new Action(delegate()
            {
                brush.set_image_brush(wb);
            }));
        }
```

Comment: Hi Palak - just to clarify, that is not the part of the code that is causing problems. It is during the creation of the bitmap itself - I still get the slow down if I comment out the brush setting entirely. Thanks anyway.